# Elegant solution to remove trailing 0's with precision set

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, std

Is there any elegant solution using the `std` C++ or `Boost` libraries to output a `double` to `std::cout` in a way that the following conditions are met:

1. scientific notation is disabled
2. the precision for the decimal part is 6
3. however, trailing `0`'s (for the decimal part) are not printed out

For example:

```
double d = 200000779998;
std::cout << `[something]` << d;
```

should print out exactly `200000779998`. `[something]` should possibly be a `noexcept` combination of some existing manipulators.

This is **not** a solution to the problem:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << std::fixed << d;
```

because it prints out `200000779998.000000` with trailing `0`'s

Comment: Do you mean you would like the fractional part to print out if it is non-zero, i.e. a non whole number? i.e. 12345.67

Comment: I fixed the question

Comment: @skypjack No. The OP wants `3.14` to print as `3.14`, but not as `3.140000`. The OP wants to support up to 6 decimal places like so, so that `3.14159265` would print as `3.141592` (maybe rounded, unimportant to my explanation), and `3.1451` would print as `3.1451`

Comment: @Justin You're right. Just re-read the question. My fault. ;-)

Comment: @MoonMoo yes, the fractional part should not be seen if 0 (given the precision)

Comment: I would be tempted to do the processing textually; to convert to a string, then remove trailing zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `fixed` manipulator, you can try to use (abuse?) `defaultfloat`. As far as I understand, it chooses either fixed or scientific based on the ability to put the number within the specified precision. As a result you can set the precision to the number of digits of the integral part + the requested fractional precision (6 in your case).

```cpp
double d = 200000779998;
std::cout << std::setprecision(integralDigits(d) + 6) << d << std::endl;
```

[You can try it here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b66d73f500f9b6d)

Answer (score -1):

Hard to prove a negative, but I would assume no.

The requirements are inconsistent with any normal use. Space efficiency dictates a binary format.  6 digits (decimal) of precision suggests a format intended for human readers, who can't churn through lots of data. And humans have no issue dealing with a consistent 6 digit format.

So, you're basically targeting a format that has no obvious audience, and that is why I would be surprised if there is support for that.

Comment: I'd say inconsistent with current practice. But, it is absolutely a sensible idea that unnecessary zeros should be removed (even, it would be a sensible idea that fractional digits that have no real meaning (because the precision is less), be ignored.)

Comment: Disagree. I actually think that the format OP's asking (generalizing 6 to any suitable N) is probably the most convenient for human being. It's both space efficient (considering screen space, not memory space) and readable. Compare [1, 2, 3.08, 5.0869] with [1.000000, 2.000000, 3.080000, 5.086900]